# Google Docs multiple criteria counting formula

Tags: excel, google-docs, formula

I would like to create a Google Docs formula which will count and sum, how many times ONE OF the words appear in the column. i.e.I have values in Sheet1 - column A, and in Sheet2 - column A1 I would like to count (sum), how many times Google **OR** Yahoo **OR** Ask appears in Sheet1-column A, (see the example). How this can be done? Thanx!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula should work in either Google docs or Excel

`=sum(countif(sheet1!A:A,{"Ask","Yahoo","Google"}))`